# What's more resource intensive? PHP or Python?

Tags: php, python, resources

My current web host allows for up to 25 processes running at once. From what I can figure, Python scripts take up a spot in processes, but PHP doesn't?

I get a 500 error if more than 25 processes are running at once (unlikely, but still a hassle), so I was wondering if it would be easier on the server if I were to port my site over to PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: You say that your current web host allows for up to 25 processes running at once. Does that not mean that, you are not allowed to run more than 25 processes. Why would you do that? What do you mean by python scripts take up spot in processes.

Comment: How is Python being served (mod_python, wsgi, etc?) and what does your apache configuration look like?  To make a real determination you have to compare apples with apples.

Comment: The best solution would be to find a different host.  Any host that limits you based upon processes instead of other more meaningful metrics (such as CPU, memory use, etc) is not worth your money.  Find a better host and move on...

Comment: I'd mostly agree with @ircmaxell here... if you're actually doing a level of traffic where you care about limits, find a host that has sane ones.

Comment: Change your hoster ;) Really, you'll find another one which allows arbitrary (to some extent) processes for the same money ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using HostGator. **Switch hosts.** Their shared server offerings should be used by very low traffic, brochure sites as they cram 100's of vhosts onto each server.

If you can't switch, ensure you're setup to use mod_php (not suPHP or cgi) or Python equivalent. Otherwise, new processes will be spawned on each request and you'll be serving up blank pages in no time.

Comment: You're right on my host, thanks! Any good hosts you'd reccomend that can host more than one domain, that has reasonable prices and good servers?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.webhostingtalk.com/ for deals. Sales people from hosting companies are always posting good hosting deals there.

Comment: Would HostGators VPS be reasonable? Or should I look for a VPS somewhere else? Or should I just get another shared hosting from a different provider?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you have PHP/Python set up. If you have, say, Apache loading PHP via mod_php, then it doesn't actually spawn a new process. Likewise, if you were using, say, [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) to handle web requests, then the webserver itself is already running the Python process, and thus there's no additional Python processes required.

Basically... don't change languages just to alter the number of processes you have running. Instead, figure out what methods your current language has to reduce the process count.